# Multi-User & parallel & Dynamic workflow in Django

Tags: python, django, bpmn

I'm looking for the best solution for the development of workflow engine in Django (Django-Rest-Framework) by this requirement :

- permission checking/task assignment options
- Parallel workflows allow to have several active tasks at once and probably have some sort of parallel sync/join functionality
- dynamic workflows typically could be configuring by changing the contents of workflow database tables

The approach I found:

- one approach is BPMN engines, and use the [SpiffWorkflow](https://github.com/sartography/SpiffWorkflow) package(which is python pure not Django)
- one other approach is to use [camunda](https://docs.camunda.io/) API (can create limitations)
- or use Django-based workflows packages that I did not find a package that supports Multi-user(permission) & Parallel & Dynamic workflows

What is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: No one had a solution?

Comment: do you have an answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by django goflow package ([github](https://github.com/zen4ever/django-goflow)).
this package supports :

- permission checking by user Group
- task assignment to specific user or a group (push and pull strategeis)
- dynamic design allow changes in workflow steps, transitions, permissions ,...
- Exclusive gateway (xor gateway) and Parallel gateway (and gateway)
- Any type of events (Message, Timer, Error, ...)